The max() and Min() functions works differently on Redshift with group by
I am trying to find the active hours for users on a system and when we group by the date the min() and max() functions returns dates outside the range.
The query I used is :
select
  cast(trndte as date) as activity_date,usr_id,
  user_name,
  prt_client_id,
  actcod,
  min(begdte) as start_time,
  max(enddte) as end_time,
  (max(enddte) - min(begdte)) as active_hrs,
  count(distinct(prtnum)) as SKUs,
  (count(frstol) + count(tostol)) as locations,
  sum(TRNQTY) Quantity
from by.by_bi_daily_tran 
where cast( trndte as date) between '2024-04-01' and '2024-04-22'
  and prt_client_id = 'MUJI'
  and actcod = 'TRLR_LOAD'   
group by cast(trndte as date), usr_id, user_name, prt_client_id, actcod;

For this row:

I would expect the MIN and MAX timestamps from the same activity date, but it is certainly not working. Anyone familiar with this ?

You are grouping by trndte and taking the max() and min() of enddte and begdte.  Why would expect these other columns to not fall outside of your grouping?  Is there some unspoken dependency in the data?  Have you looked at the source data?
Note: In the future if you expect people to read your code please format it for readability.  Also, don't post images of data as this is hard to read.
